# What is the best way to join multiple element values into a new string in xslt 2.0

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I need to join multiple element values into a new string separated with whitespace, what is the best way to do this? I am using xslt 2.0.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at the [string-join](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions/#func-string-join) function.

```
<xsl:value-of select="string-join(/path/to[1]/nodes/text(), ' ')" />
```

Comment: @tomalak: Now it's my turn to say that there's nothing I can add to this answer :).  I already added my +1 earlier today.